# How to set default type @typeparam TValue = bool in blazor(.razor page)

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

We have provided the TValue support in the checked property for the Checkbox component. How to set default type @typeparam TValue = bool in blazor(.razor page)

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering
@inherits BaseComponent;
@implements ICheckBox;
@typeparam TValue = bool;
```

Answer (score 8):

> This is a **known issue** https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13619

but **work around** I do in a project is

```
public class DateTimePickerComponent : DateTimePickerComponent<DateTime?> { } // default Type value

public class DateTimePickerComponent<T> : BaseSubComponent { .... } // all business here
```

and in Component I inherts from one of

```
@inherits DateTimePickerComponent  // default type will be DateTime?
@inherits DateTimePickerComponent<DateTime> // this also work
```

Comment: As far as I can tell though this prevents you from later setting the type to another type when referencing the used component. I believe the point of providing the default would be to allow you to default to it ONLY if you don't have an explicit type to provide. Still I could see how this might be useful in certain situations.